# Filesystem vs UploadedFile vs Disk in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, filesystems

I'm currently working on project using Laravel and I'm really lost about how to handle uploaded files properly.

What I need is to store the uploaded file to a specific directory (private, only accessible by the server), it's a CSV file and I need to process its data. So, I'm planning to use [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) method to read the file line by line, however, I need a file handle for that.

According to the docs, the uploaded files are stored in a temporary directory, and you can retrieve an `UploadedFile` object denoting the file by calling `file('variablename')` method on the request object. Since I need to persist those files I would need to call the store method as the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#storing-uploaded-files) states (or maybe use a different approach). Sadly, the store method returns the path relative to "disk root", which here means a `Disk` object configured in a `FileSystem` object. Probably using `fopen` with that path isn't going to work, I would need an absolute path instead.

A dirty workaround that I came up with consists in playing with the [storage_path](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4796fe5b0b698c39a0c707287154ade9ed47080d/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php#L673) method, since I know what is the configured root on the local disk (`storage_path('app')`).

It would be something like this

```
$local_path = $file->store('uploads', 'local');
$abspath = storage_path('app') . '/' . $local_path;
// Pass the absolute path to the business layer
// In the business layer...
$fh = fopen($abspath, 'r');
// Do the thing
```

Is there any better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out how to get the absolute path, however the method is not officially documented but this works for me:

```
$abspath = Storage::disk('local')->getDriver()->getAdapter()->applyPathPrefix($local_path);
```